# AngularJS custom ordering with orderBy

Tags: angularjs

I have a select dropdown with different sorting options, one of which is rarity. The rarities are common, uncommon, rare, ..., etc however (as expected) when sort by rarity is selected, the items are ordered by rarity in alphabetical order. Is there a way to specify a different way of ordering the rarities - that is, in a fixed order?

The rarities are common, uncommon, rare, mythical, legendary, ancient, immortal, arcana (from Dota2 in case you're wondering.)

So for example, instead of alphabetical order of rarities which is the default, I would like it in the order displayed above.

Below is what I've tried:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-sorting" ng-model="orderProp">
        <option value="">No Sorting</option>
        <option value="used_by_heroes">Hero</option>
        <option value="class">Type</option>
        <option value="rarityOrder">Rarity</option>
</select>
...
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ... orderBy:orderProp>
    ...
</div>
```

And within the directive:

```
var mapping = {
                'common': 0,
                'uncommon': 1,
                'rare': 2,
                ...
};
scope.rarityOrder = function(item) {
   return mapping[item.item_rarity];
};
```

Comment: Example? What do you mean by fixed order?

Comment: Added a bit of clarity.

Comment: @zeroflagL still doesn't work :(. I'm still wondering how it knows to reference the property 'item_rarity' - although I'm wondering if you are allowed to have a function as an option?

Comment: In fact, to confirm when i put it as 'orderBy: rarityOrder' with no option this works. But if it's selected via <option value="rarityOrder .. this doesn't work?

Comment: Actually, when you use a select like this, orderProp will not represent the function you defined, but an ordinary string, thus you will try to order by an inexistant key. To avoid this, there is probably a better way, but quickly, I'd use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/vkyzjwb8/2/ , you always order using a function, and the function itself switch if you selected rarity or not (it's the same solution proposed by @zeroflagL, but wrapped in a different function)

Comment: @DotDotDot Great thanks, this solves my problem. Perhaps in the future I'll look for a better way like you've said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a mapping function.

In your HTML:

```
"items | orderBy: rarityOrder"
```

In your controller:

```
var mapping =  {
  'rare': 0,
  'uncommon': 1
  ...
};

$scope.rarityOrder = function(rarity) {
  return mapping[rarity]; 
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this working for me. Just a little confused about how the parameter would be passed to this function?

Comment: @Titus the parameter is passed by the `orderBy` filter. You just tell it what function to use.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
  angular.module('orderByExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.friends =
          [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
           {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];
      $scope.predicate = '-age';
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <pre>Sorting predicate = {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
  <hr/>
  [ <a href="" ng-click="predicate=''">unsorted</a> ]
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=false">Name</a>
          (<a href="" ng-click="predicate = '-name'; reverse=false">^</a>)</th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'phone'; reverse=!reverse">Phone Number</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'age'; reverse=!reverse">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

May be the above code could help you!!

You can modify your  to include 'predicate' and that should work I guess.